# PHP input file, add date or random number to filename

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file via input type file and save the file to a folder and then save the file name in the database.

the code below adds the file path to the file name, which is not what I want because when I call it the output looks like this images/articles/../images/articles/

```
if($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0){
     $target_path = "../images/articles/";
     $target_path = $target_path . time() . rand(11, 99) . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
      updateDB($_POST['id'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['preview'], $_POST['description'], $target_path);
}
```

I also tried this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['name'] . date(‘ymdhis’));
```

but this adds the date after the extension.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0){
     $target_path_folder = "../images/articles/";
$fileName =  time() . rand(11, 99) . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);

     $target_path = $target_path_folder .$fileName;
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
      updateDB($_POST['id'], $_POST['title'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['preview'],        $_POST['description'], $fileName);
}
```

Should help